# Azure HBASE REST - simple get failing for colfam:col

Tags: api, rest, azure, hbase

This should be a very simple one (been searching for a solution all day - read a thousand and a half posts).

I put a test row in my HBASE table in hbase shell:
  put 'iEngine','testrow','SVA:SourceName','Journal of Fun'

I can get the value for a column family using the REST API in DHC Chrome:
  https://ienginemaster.azurehdinsight.net/hbaserest/iEngine/testrow/SVA

I can't seem to get it for the specific cell:  https://ienginemaster.azurehdinsight.net/hbaserest/iEngine/testrow/SVA:SourceName

```
{
"Row": [{
    "key": "dGVzdHJvdw==",
    "Cell": [{
        "column": "U1ZBOlNvdXJjZU5hbWU=",
        "timestamp": 1440602453975,
        "$": "Sm91cm5hbCBvZiBGdW4="
    }]
}]
```

}

I get back a 400 error.

When successfully asking for just the family, I get back:

I tried replacing the encoded value for SVA:SourceName, and a thousand other things.   I'm assuming I'm missing something simple.

Also, the following works:

```
hbase(main):012:0> get 'iEngine', 'testrow', 'SVA:SourceName'
```

COLUMN                               CELL

SVA:SourceName                      timestamp=1440602453975, value=Journal of Fun

1 row(s) in 0.0120 seconds

hbase(main):013:0>

Answer (score 0):

I opened a case with Microsoft support.  I received confirmation that it is a bug (IIS and the colon separator not working). They are working on a fix - they are slightly delayed as the decide on the "best" way to fix it.